# cant understand how each method works here

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying a simple thing with each & setTimeout function. I want the letters of a name will appear distinctively & at separate(gradual) time. Suppose, letters of NAZ should appear this way, first N second A last Z. but, here I can see output is AZN then ZNA then NAZ. What I feel, I've a wrong comprehension of how 'each' works actually. but, the output in console is shown exactly as I intended. Have a look at this.

```
    $('div.promise').each(function(index, promise){
        setTimeout(function()

            {
                $('.showPromise').append(promise);
                console.log($(promise).text());

$('.promise').css({"display":"block"})},1000*(index+2));    

});}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanje/425konu3/17/

How can I show the output as shown in console? & why all the divs appear altogether at certain time? Please help me find out the mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is following statement inside your `setTimeout`:

```
$('.promise').css({"display":"block"})
```

It makes all div's with class `promise` visible together. You should use this instead:

```
$(promise).css({"display":"block"})
```

```js
var showAnimation=function(){
  
  $('div.promise').each(function(index, promise){
   setTimeout(function(){
     // $('.showPromise').append(promise);
     console.log($(promise).text());
         $(promise).css({"display":"block"})
      },1000*(index+2));
   });//each()
  }//showAnimation()
$('button').on('click', showAnimation);
```

```css
.promise {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.showPromise {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}



.as-console-wrapper{display: none !important;}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 
<button>call</button>
<div class="showPromise">
  <div class="promise">N</div>
  <div class="promise">A</div>
  <div class="promise">Z</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting display on the whole class each time. You need to only show each instance in the loop. you can simplify and do that using `show()`.

The `append()` part doesn't really make much sense either so I removed it

```js
var showAnimation = function() {

  $('div.promise').each(function(index, promise) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(promise).show();
      }, 1000 * (index + 2));
  });
}
$('button').on('click', showAnimation);
```

```css
.promise {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.showPromise {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<button>call</button>
<div class="showPromise">
  <div class="promise">N</div>
  <div class="promise">A</div>
  <div class="promise">Z</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I've got the point. But just one more thing, while preserved the old wronged code, why it appeared AZN ZNA NAZ? why not this NAZ NAZ NAZ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. There is only one letter in each `promise` element

Answer (score 0):

@charlietfl Perhaps, I could figure out what's happened here. Please have a look at the existing code

```
    $('.showPromise').append(promise);
    $('.promise').show();},1000*(index+2));
https://jsfiddle.net/425konu3/20/
```

output:
AZN (shows then hides)
ZNA (shows then hides)
NAZ (persists)

I asked what’s hack here, why not NAZ NAZ NAZ. It turns out that as append moves the selected element as the last child & all the divs are available to display right at the moment by virtue of $('.promise').show(), they are shown up altogether in a manner that the first div is appended as last while the next adjacent div sits at 0 index & the rest sits next to it.

First time, N appends(last index), A(index 0), Z(index 1), so AZN appears.
Second time, A appends(last index), Z(index 0), N(index 1), so ZNA appears.
Last time, Z appends(last index), N(index 0), A(index 1), so NAZ appears.